# Auto crop text(signature) from image and change background color using Imagemagick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick

Need to auto crop text(signature)from an images(sample image:[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGN1o.png) )and Need to change background color of cropped image. 
Need to achieve this using Imagemagick. 
Is it any possible way to achieve these ?
I am using version ImageMagick 7.0.7-28

[williamson image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMZdw.jpg)
[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xm8jk.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by auto-crop? You can use ImageMagick -trim to get the signature cropped to its bounding box and then use -fuzz -opaque to change the background.

Input:

[image]

```
magick signature.png -fuzz 20% -trim +repage -fill pink -opaque white result.png
```

[image]

Or you can just make the background transparent.

```
magick signature.png -fuzz 20% -trim +repage -transparent white result2.png
```

[image]

Comment: Auto-crop means Need to crop an exact text(signature) from an image. I used above two commands but i can't achieve those two for image an new following image LINK: [williamson_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMZdw.jpg) . I need to crop exact signature from image and change background color

Comment: I have no universal solution. Each one will depend upon the image and it signature and background color. For your new image, try `magick signature2.jpg -fuzz 15% -trim +repage -fill white +opaque "#5B000C" result.png`. I still do not know what you mean by "crop". Can you show an example?

Comment: Example: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xm8jk.jpg]  Need to crop rectangle box and need to change background color for it. In above command script mentioned by you was working but it getting change text color also. I Don't want to change text color. Only background color should change.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any color change in the text, though it is not quite as smooth. Adjust the fuzz value as desired to remove the gray and keep the text as smooth as you can.

Input:

[image]

ImageMagick 7 command:

```
magick signature3.jpeg -fuzz 15% -fill white +opaque "#5B000C" -trim +repage result.png
```

[image]